# get form validation from google form api

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-docs, google-forms

I'm trying to get google form as json. I get all questions and it's type. I want the validation of the form
I want form validation tooo how to Include form validations
Is it possible to get all validations from google form

```
fetch(` https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/${id}`, 
     { method: 'GET', headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer          ${token}` } })
```

response look like this and I want validation info too

````
    "formId": "....",
    "info": {
        "title": "Event feedback",
        "description": "Thank you for participating in our event. We hope you had as much fun attending as we did organizing it.\n\nWe want to hear your feedback so we can keep improving our logistics and content. Please fill this quick survey and let us know your thoughts (your answers will be anonymous).",
        "documentTitle": "Event Feedback"
    },
    "revisionId": "00000004",
    "responderUri": "....",
    "items": [
        {
            "itemId": "....",
            "title": "How satisfied were you with the event?",
            "questionItem": {
                "question": {
                    "questionId": "...",
                    "required": true,
                    "scaleQuestion": {
                        "low": 1,
                        "high": 5,
                        "lowLabel": "Not very",
                        "highLabel": "Very much"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "itemId": "....",
            "title": "How relevant and helpful do you think it was for your job?",
            "questionItem": {
                "question": {
                    "questionId": "....",
                    "required": true,
                    "scaleQuestion": {
                        "low": 1,
                        "high": 5,
                        "lowLabel": "Not very",
                        "highLabel": "Very much"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        
        {
            "itemId": "....",
            "questionGroupItem": {
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "questionId": "....",
                        "required": true,
                        "rowQuestion": {
                            "title": "Accommodation"
                        }
                    },]
            }

        }
    ]
} ```
````

I need form validation in response data